# How to do sum of 90 days and 91 days in leap year in sql server

Tags: sql-server

My table name is **C_Payment_Service_Fee** and table contain data that is below

```
select top 10 * from c_payment_service_fee
amount        crn_dt                payment_mode
19.99   2015-08-11 23:06:58.877         CC
19.99   2015-05-11 13:30:59.603         CC
39.95   2016-06-29 10:26:09.380         CC
29.99   2015-09-13 22:22:57.703         CC
24.99   2016-04-15 14:59:22.130         CC
22.49   2014-08-29 15:09:39.230         CC
24.99   2013-01-15 15:51:22.097         CC
26.95   2016-07-06 10:26:04.507         CC
14.99   2011-12-15 17:53:17.527         CC
15.99   2014-04-09 11:51:27.377         CC
```

Now I need to sum(amount) from January 01 to March 31 of every year.

Comment: What is the expected result

Comment: what do you mean by sum? could you please be more clear?

Comment: you can get 'quarter' adjusted for leap years by the formula (month(dob) - 1)/3 + 1         IN my case the date is dob, but you can plug any date in - let us know if there's any other factors you are considering here - are you perhaps wanting to know how many days there are in any given 'quarter'?

Comment: I have edited my question.... I hope it will helpful

Comment: @VinayakaN - How to identify `month`.

Comment: ok wait .... I will give complete information......

Comment: @Prdp - MONTH(any_date_field_or_variable) is a built in SQL function - it will just give you the MONTH number (1-12) of any date you pass to it

Comment: @AndrewDeighton - When I asked that question, OP did not added this column `crn_dt`

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEDIFF(dd, @from, @to)
```

This will give you number of days between two dates

Comment: If i use datediff function I should mention date manually..... I should not  enter manually It should be automatic.......

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as FirstQamount 
                     FROM  C_Payment_Service_Fee
                            WHERE MONTH(crn_dt) IN (1,2,3)
```

does get that get you nearer?

Answer (score 0):

The wording "every year" is a little unclear -- I can't tell if you want them grouped by year or not.

If you just want all the January-March amounts in one lump sum:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM c_payment_service_fee
WHERE MONTH(crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
```

If you want to see the January-March totals for each year separately, add the year and a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount, YEAR(crn_dt) as crn_yr
FROM c_payment_service_fee
WHERE MONTH(crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
GROUP BY YEAR(crn_dt);
```

Be aware having the MONTH() function in the WHERE clause will make the query non-SARGable. SQL Server won't be able to evaluate the WHERE clause without pulling every crn_dt value and then running MONTH() against them. The bigger the underlying table, the worse the performance penalty for non-SARGability will be.